# 'new File' is redundant

Tags: java, file, warnings

I have the following code:

```
try(ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("users.dat")))){
    o.writeObject(users);
}
```

My IDE is issuing a warning:

`'new File' is redundant`

I understand `FileOutputStream` has an overloaded constructor that accepts a string as its path, but isn't it better practice to create a new file object? If not, how so?

Comment: Using File is better if you want to re-use it. Since the object is inlined, it can not be the case and constructing a new File uses more resources than just passing a String.

Comment: "better practice"? How would that be?

Comment: @khelwood I'm guessing he is referring to using the methods of File, Path, URI and URL classes for file/path management instead of manipulating a String, since that doesn't consider the underlying OS. (Okay he probably didn't think about that, but still)

Answer (score 3):

Because creating a FileOutputStream with a string does the exact same thing.

```
public FileOutputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but isn't it better practice to create a new file object?

practices serve a purpose. Without understanding the purpose, you're just blindly applying these pithy rules, just hoping that rigorous application of oversimplified rules somehow makes you a good coder.

Coding is, unfortunately, just not that simple.

So, what is this practice attempting to accomplish?

Perhaps the idea is: Things should be conveyed in terms of what they are; `users.dat` is a path, so it should be in a path object, and not a string.

That's not a bad idea, but here that information is fleeting. Not stored in any variable, and the fact that you're passing a string to a constructor of the type `FileOutputStream` surely takes away all doubt.

And wasn't that the point of the exercise in the first place? To make code more legible? It just doesn't apply here.

It may apply in other scenarios, of course. But, you opted into this: This isn't a warning that basic java generates; you opted into a linting tool that does this.

You'll find that these pithy, oversimplified maxims that are trying to spin a good idea into a rigid rule will inevitably clash, with rigid application of one good idea mutually exclusive with rigid application of another.

The idea of avoiding meaningless wrapping is *also* a good idea. It makes code needlessly longer, and may hint at you writing code in a non-idiomatic fashion (after all, the `FOS` constructor that takes a string exists. Unless you consider that constructor banned for all purposes...)

The fix is simple: To write good code? It takes a good programmer. A linting tool is just that. A tool. It doesn't write code by itself. If it bothers you here, you may have a point. Then turn it off.

NB: The fact that you're using the old API which is using the somewhat suspicious term 'File', whereas what it really represents is a Path, is not helping here. Check out `java.nio.file` - I don't really like this second take on the API either, but it's better than java.io.File at least.